# How to deconstruct an array of string to pass it as params of Serilog in C#

Tags: c#, serilog

I am working with Serilog.

I have this code

```
var message = "Age: {Age}, Weight: {Weight}";

// the list is ordered with the keys in the message
var elements = new List<string>{"15yo","60kgs"};

// call log method
logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, message, elements.ToArray());
```

```
// Expected log: 
"Age: 15yo, Weight: 60kgs"

// Actual log: 
"Age: ["15yo", "60kgs"], Weight: {Weight}"
```

Actually instead of deconstructing the array into multiple params, it takes the whole array as a single parameter and it replace the first key

Any help is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the input to `object[]` - this will call the correct overload of Log - the one with the `[ParamArray]`, as opposed to the one that the IDE will show you if you hover (which is treating it as one arg, which just happens to be an array)

```cs
elements.Cast<object>().ToArray()
```